# Adding custom options in pop up menu of linux on clicking specific file formats

Tags: linux, python-2.7, user-interface, gnome-3

I want to add '`Download subtitle`' option on the context pop up menu (menu appearing on right clicking on the selected file) of all video files.  How can I do this when I am using python as the language?

Answer (score 1):

From [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91876/is-it-possible-to-add-an-item-to-the-nautilus-right-click-menu/91898#91898) it appears you should install the `nautilus-actions` package and run it like:

```
$ sudo yum install nautilus-actions
$ nautilus-actions-config-tool
```

Since you are just telling nautilus to invoke a command you can implement it in any language: python, shell, Perl, etc.

Comment: but how will it categorise video files only

Comment: edit the media types allowed in "`Mimetypes`" so `*/*` is not included but `video/*` is